# C++ Memory-Mapped-IO with a template based API

Tags: c++, templates, embedded

Suppose you have a class like this one. The class relies on a template parameter to a memory-mapped-io SPI.

```cpp
template <std::uintptr_t SPI_BASE, ...
class Spi {
...
}
```

I always used `static_assert` to forbid someone from passing a wrong pointer.

like: `static_assert(SPI_BASE == SPI1_BASE || ...)`. This unfortunately kills my test cases as I can only use `real` SPI pointers in unit tests.

My next guess was to just use `SPI_Typedef *` as template parameter. Which is not possible because `reinterpret_cast` is not possible to use in a constexpr context.

`#define SPI1 ((SPI_TypeDef *) SPI1_BASE)`
Is an example how these are defined in the C include libraries.

Once you try to init your template you will get issues as you `reinterpret_cast`.

```
Spi<SPI1, ...>
```

So I tried with limited knowledge a little bit of template fiddling. But that results in the same reinterpret_casts issues.

```cpp
// this is a bad aproach (not working)
template <typename T, std::uintptr_t Ptr>
struct MemPtr {
    static constexpr T *pointer = reinterpret_cast<T *>(Ptr);
};

constexpr auto spi_addr = mem_ptr<SPI_TypeDef, SPI1_BASE>{};
spi<spi_addr::pointer, ...
```

Is there any way I can fix this while maintaining my templated API ?
I mean it would be possible to `reinterpret_cast` a const variable at runtime but then I could not pass the variable as a template parameter anymore.

I'm also open minded to other approaches.
There are no c++ version restrictions for a solution

I could use an `auto` template parameter. But I still want to have type safety.

Comment: What do you think you need `constexpr` for? Clearly nothing related to memory-mapped I/O can possibly be computed at compile time.

Comment: you need `constexpr` to pass the pointer as a template parameter.

Comment: It is impossible to write 
`Spi<SPI1, ...>` as `SPI1` would expand to `Spi<((SPI_TypeDef *) SPI1_BASE), ...>` which is the same as a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I could just use `std::uintptr_t` or `auto` as template parameter for the `Spi class` but then I could pass >every< possible pointer. Not just pointers to `SPI_TypeDef`s

Comment: The main issue with these `plain c` embedded libs is that they define the MMIO in plain defines without actually initializing the objects. So you typicly have just a reinterpret_cast to some memory

Comment: Hardware registers are already initialized by the hardware itself. And since you were distracted by adding as many C++11 features in the code as possible, you forgot to make the registers actually volatile, so the code is fundamentally broken in its base core purpose. This is a perfect example why we don't use C++ in embedded systems. Soon as you let someone use it, they keep coming up with solutions to problems that don't exist, using features that they don't need to solve those non-existing problems, creating other problems while they are at it.